# jQuery edit iframe attributes on click event on Firefox

Tags: jquery, iframe

When I try to edit an iframe body using jQuery. I can't get it work. But with the standard JS, I get it work.

My standard js code:

```
$("#add-page").click(function () {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    $("#page-frames").append(iframe);
    iframe.onload = function (e) {
        var content = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument);
        if (content)
            content = content.document;

        var iBody = $(content.body);
        //etc
    }
});
```

That work fine.

But with jQuery, I get typeerror. I did not write the click event. But they are in the click event:

```
var iframe = $("<iframe></iframe>");
$("#page-frames").append(iframe);
iframe.load(function(){...});
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function[Learn More]  jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4:18892
    r.fn.load https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4:18892
    <anonymous> file:///home/guervyl/test.html:9:1
```

And This next code return $(this) as the parent page document

```
var iframe = $("<iframe></iframe>");
$("#page-frames").append(iframe);
iframe.ready(function(){ 
   //$(this) is not the iframe. But the iframe parent page document
});
```

Whats the problem with jQuery?

Comment: Could you please edit to include the error returned?

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: That error sometimes returns when you use jQuery deprecated events. Try changing iframe.load(function(){...}); to iframe.on('load', function(){ ...});

Comment: Yes. The `iframe.on('load', function(){ ...});` works. But from the jQuery `.load` [page](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) they do not say it's deprecated. And why `.ready` event does not return `this` as the iframe as the `iframe.on('load', function(){ ...});` does.

Comment: Sorry, it don't say it's deprecated, but it is in the deprecated section.